# How do I control the WMP from command line/batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, media-player

I am wondering, how I can control the Windows Media Player from the command line or a batch file.
With "control" I do not mean open or close the WMP, but 'Skip forwards one title', 'Skip backwards one title', 'pause', 'resume', 'increase volume' and 'decrease volume'.

I've searched already, but the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx) is not really what I'm searching for :/

Comment: Different versions of Windows Media Player had different command line options.  None were fully featured TTBOMK.

Comment: for skip,pause,resume you'll rather need `sendkeys` and getting windows media player on focus

Comment: @foxidrive: THX - but I think that those options should also exist in earlier versions of the WMP.....

@ npocmaka: Do you know how to do it by cmd?

Comment: Maybe a starting point is to mention which version of WMP you need to use.

Comment: @foxidrive: I'm using version 12.0.7601.18150

Comment: I don't think you can control WMP like that from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to either write or download a utility to do this.  WMP has an object model that you can access via ActiveX or COM if you're willing to do some programming.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For generic operations like play/pause, next track, etc, you can also write a simple program that either sends VK_MEDIA_* keypresses to the WMP window, or simply use SendMessage to send the equivalent WM_APPCOMMAND messages.